# What is the て-form doing in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, て-form

> 当初とすげ替わった目的、アイズ・ヴァレンシュタインさんのことも**含めて**。

I'm not sure what the て-form does in this sentence.

Could it be short for ている?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say something definitive without more context, but it's probably either one of the followings:

1. The [te-form used as a request](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13003/5010). "Please include things about Wallenstein, too."
2. The main verb after 含めて (教えてください, 話そう, etc.) is omitted, because it's already specified before this sentence. "(Tell me about the incident.) Including things about Wallenstein."

Comment: 文脈はたぶん[これ](http://lightnovel-box.info/archives/327)かと

Comment: Oh then, "何だって思うようにはいかない" is the omitted phrase. "Things won't always go well. Including the affairs about Wallenstein (which is not going well, either)."

Comment: How do you figure out what is omitted? Does it just come with experience?

Comment: The sentences before this basically say how difficult his life has been, so I think it's natural to understand this sentence along the same line, too.

Answer (score 2):

No, it can't be short for ている. ヴァレンシュタインさんのことも含めて means "including things about Wallenstein"