# Sentence Ending て form

Tags: grammar, て-form

> 妻が死んで、子供が家を出て。
>
> Then my wife died, and my kids left home.

Is the sentence ending て a contraction for another expression? If so can someone list the possible expressions for any sentence ending て form?

Also is the で connecting the sentences the reason-giving で?

Thank you!

Comment: 1: the guy just did not finish his sentence as everyone does in japan. 2: no.

Answer (score 5):

By ending the sentence like this, the speaker is implying he has something more to say. His wife died, his kids left home, and that may not be the end of his story. Or he may just want to add how sad he was.

He may continue his story right after this sentence, but the remaining part may be simply omitted when it's obvious.

> 「明日映画に行こう。」「あー、今、お金がなくて…。」
>   "Let's go to a movie tomorrow." "Er, I don't have money now, so..."

The で in 死んで is basically the same as て, but [て will be voiced after some verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_verb_conjugation#Summary_of_verb_conjugations) (*rendaku* phenomenon).

*(Not to be confused [て as a casual request](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13003/5010).)*

Comment: Is ending a sentence with the て form used in the same situations that one could end a sentence with が or けど?

Comment: Not much. We anticipate "but" or "by the way" contents after が and けど, but the topic still on the same track after て.