# Why the te-form 開けて is used here

Tags: て-form

In an episode on Crayon Shin-Chan, Shin-Chan says

> 開けて！

In this situation, he was knocking the door (For the second time he was knocking. His mom has already told him that he should properly say "I'm home", as he didn't use the proper greeting. Shin-Chan replied that "You should not take a child's words too seriously".)

Shin-Chan's mom replies from inside the house

> 開けません！

She was angry on him for returning home late.

Jisho says there is this verb 開ける, which may mean

> to open (a door, etc.)

But why Shin-Chan uses the te-form of the verb? He could at most use the imperative form of the verb, which is 開けろ.

Another question, why Shin-Chan's mom uses the polite masu-form of the verb with her kid, while Shin-Chan didn't use it with her mom?

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13003/9831

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically speaking, 「開{あ}けて！」 in this context/situation is ***not*** in the te-form.

Rather, the 「て」 here is a sentence-ending particle that is used to form a ***request*** or a ***light kind of imperative***.  This usage of 「て」 is *extremely* common in informal Japanese.

Thus, 「開けて！」 means the same thing as 「開けてください。」 or 「開けてくれ。」, meaning "(Please) open (the door)!".  Shin-chan is not using the te-form even though it is physically the same as the te-form.  The grammar and meaning/usage is completely different from the te-form.

> Another question, why Shin-Chan's mom uses the polite masu-form of the verb with her kid, while Shin-Chan didn't use it with her mom?

It is not uncommon for Japanese moms to use the masu-form with their kids and husbands.  This may sound weird to you, but not to us native speakers.

Comment: Wiktionary page for する has this sentence: 　一人にしないで   .   So is this sentence also a request of the type you mentioned?  Then, is  しないで the negative te-form of する ? But doesn't する have the negative te-form      しなくて  instead ?

Comment: The negative te form of a verb like しなくて does not have the meaning of making a request. All other verbs are the same. You have 来ないで、食べないで、走らないで, etc. While なくて a lot of times is used more like an adverb or it has something after it. E.g. 来なくていい means "you don't have to come", then also 何も食べなくて学校までに来た "I came to school without eating anything". Though ないで which also has this meaning is more common to use.